# IE invalid argument because vars equal NaN

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, invalid-argument

The penultimate line gives an "Invalid argument" error in IE11 - other browsers are fine run the code fine.

```
var active = $('.interactivemap-minimap-active', this.el);

if (x === undefined) x = self.x;
if (y === undefined) y = self.y;

var width = Math.round(self.container.width() / self.contentWidth / self.scale * this.el.width()),
height = Math.round(self.container.height() / self.contentHeight / self.scale * this.el.height()),
top = Math.round(-y / self.contentHeight / self.scale * this.el.height()),
left = Math.round(-x / self.contentWidth / self.scale * this.el.width()),
right = left + width,
bottom = top + height;

console.log("pass2: width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left + ", right=" + right + ", bottom=" + bottom);

active.each(function() {
$(this)[0].style.clip = 'rect(' + top + 'px, ' + right + 'px, ' + bottom + 'px, ' + left + 'px)';
});
```

the console.log will show:

> width=Nan , height=Nan , top=Nan , left=Nan , right=Nan , bottom=Nan

If I comment out the troublesome line, the console.log will show:

> width=Nan , height=Nan , top=Nan , left=Nan , right=Nan , bottom=Nan
>
> width=140 , height=162 , top=-1 , left=0 , right=140 , bottom=161

So it looks like it takes a moment to populate those variables with actual data but it starts the last function when the are still equal to Nan and then errors.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Could you provide an example that people can use to reproduce the issue? It makes it much easier to help when it is easy to see the issue first-hand.

Comment: Weird, when I run the script locally it errors, now I've added it to the server it's fine: http://cucocreative.co.uk/client_files/testing/

Comment: Would anyone know why it errors locally? It will eventually be served over a companies intranet so I suspect it will be fine.